# Ошибка Cannot read property 'val' of null

Tags: jquery

Приветствую всех! В html документе имеется поле input, в которое пытаюсь передать значение name, получаю ошибку Cannot read property 'val' of null

Буду рад любой помощи.

```
jQuery("a#source-link").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var link_title = jQuery(this).attr("name");

  $("input#target-textfield").val(link_title);
});
```

Comment: данный код не может бросить эту ошибку, можешь сделать рабочий пример, который воспроизведет ошибку тут в сниппете либо на [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: какие еще библиотеки подключены, кроме jQuery? Проверь чему на самом деле равен `$`?

Comment: Разобрался, $ заменил на jQuery, просмотрел.

Comment: и чем на самом деле была `$`?